# What does it mean when it appears <propertie>.keyword in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a beginner in the world of Elasticsearch and And I don't know what it means when a property called .keyword. It only appears when I'm in the section "Management" > "Index Pattern".

Only those properties (propertie.keyword) have option 'aggregatable' active.

What's the difference between 'locality' and 'locality.keyword'.

And I don't get the same result when I do

```
{'match': {'locality': "Sant Climent"}}
```

or

```
{'match': {'locality.keyword': "Sant Climent"}}
```

Someone could explain to me the difference and what each thing is used for? I'm going crazy.

(I'm using the latest version of Elasticsearch BTW, 6.X).

Answer (score 0):

Your field is indexed two times: one time `locality` is indexed with a `text datatype` and is used to perform fulltext search. Your text is subvided into tokens and you can apply a filter transformation and retrieve every single word. E.G. Once you have tokenized a text you can apply a stopword list to remove unmeaningful words or a stemmer, giving the possibility to retrieve a word from its stem. You could query against this field with the `match` query. `locality.keyword` is the same content indexed as `keyword datatype`. That it means that your text is considered as a unique token and you can retrieve your content only with a literal search on that field - if you don't provide a keyword normalizer is also case sensitive!, no fulltext. You could query against this field with the `term` query. For that reason you could make aggregation only on the `keyword` field content: the server could make a kind of groupby on the field, because its content is as is it, and is not composed by differents units - the tokens.If you have any other doubt , please ask for help :-)

Comment: Thank you. If locality.keyword is considered as a unique token, could I do a search like a "like" in SLQ?

Comment: @RodriKing It depends from your content! The LIKE operator in SQL is used to search for a specified pattern in a column. If a keyword datatype is a unique token, you can't search directly for a partial pattern inside the field, only for literal search. You could retrieve a partial pattern in keyword field, using - for example - a prefix query. But you have to know why in that case you should prefer a keyword datatype instead a text one. You have to study the different queries for different datatype and also how they store its contents in ES server. Could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the [text datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) and [keyword datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html).

You can map fields as `text` and `keyword` combined like this:

```
{  
   "properties":{  
      "locality":{  
         "type":"text",
         "fields":{  
            "keyword":{  
               "type":"keyword",
               "ignore_above":256
            }
         }
      },
      ... other fields here
}
```

When doing this, you can now query the field `locality` as `text` OR you could use `locality.keyword` to query it as `keyword`.

Comment: Thank you @Diyarbakir. I didn't know the difference between them. I think I get it now. Do you know how to search on a datatype keyword as if it were a "like" in SQL?